# Using 'map' object in Jupyter notebook environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[image]

'map' object of python doesn't work in jupyter notebook. But It works well in python shell. Can you explain why? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You have apparently assigned the result of a `map()` call to `map` previously, thus overwriting the built-in function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `map` is still a value, but not a callable. Most likely, you assigned a value to it earlier in the Jupyter notebook (as jasonharper said in a comment).

You can check what type of object `map` is by executing this in a code cell:

```py
map?
```

The notebook should show an overlay window at the bottom describing the type, string representation, and docstring.